# Ruby: How to include/install .bundle?

Tags: ruby, include, bundle, require

I'm new to Ruby. I have a .bundle file. I put it in the source folder and did

```
require('my.bundle')
```

But when I call the methods in the bundle, the definition is not found. Do I have to install them or include them in some other way to access them?

I am on Ruby version 1.8.7 (latest version on Mac).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [`RVM`](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) to manage your Ruby installation, including your gems, so if you don't already have that, get it and follow the [instructions for installing](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) it. Make sure you do the part about modifying your bash startup script or you'll see weird behavior, like the wrong Ruby being called. Also, use the steps in "[RVM and RubyGems](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/)" to install your gems or you can run into weird behavior with gems being installed under the wrong or an unexpected Ruby.

Second, use the `gem` command to install gems:

```
gem install gem_to_install
```

replacing "gem_to_install" with the name of the gem you want, and it will be installed into the appropriate gem folder for your Ruby.

If you are on Ruby 1.92, and trying to `require` a gem to use as a module in your code, use:

```
require 'gemname'
```

if it is installed via the `gem` command. And, if it is a module you wrote or have in your program's directory or below it, use:

```
require_relative 'path/to/gem/gemname'
```

If you are on a Ruby < 1.9 you'll also need to add `require 'rubygems'` above your other `require` lines, then use `require './path/to/gem/gemname'`.

---

> > Thanks, but my .bundle is not in gems. How do I install/require a .bundle file I already have?

If you wrote it look into [`rubygems/gemcutter`](http://rubygems.org/) or [`bundler`](http://gembundler.com/) for info on bundling and managing gems.

You can install a gem without using the app by going into the directory containing the gem and running `setup.rb`. See http://i.loveruby.net/en/projects/setup/doc/usage.html for a decent writeup or the official docs at: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3

Comment: Thanks, but my .bundle is not in gems. How do I install/require a .bundle file I already have?

Comment: require_relative is also not defined. I did require 'rubygems' before it.

Comment: You should specify what version of Ruby you are using in your question. If `require_relative` isn't known I have to guess you are on a 1.8.n version.

Comment: I seem to be on 1.8.7 (ruby --version). According to ruby-lang.org, that's the latest version on Mac.

Comment: I'm confused. setup.rb can't be found and according to the links it is a way to install RubyGems. I have RubyGems (gems command works).

Comment: A little more fundamental, is .bundle the same as a "gem"? I have this file generated by a Makefile and want to access the functions in it. I thought it was just like a shared library or something that I could include. It is in the same folder as my script and I tried both "require 'my.bundle'" and "require 'my'", neither works. Isn't there some folder I can copy it to or something?

Comment: Ok so I downloaded the setup.rb but it doesn't do anything. I did setup.rb config. Nothing. setup.rb setup. Nothing. Then setup.rb install. It just says "rm -f InstalledFiles" What is that supposed to mean?! There's no "InstalledFiles" anywhere. It also won't take files as parameters, so how would I install them??

Comment: It really sounds like you are making it a whole lot harder than it should be. WHAT gem do you want to install? Where is Ruby 1.8.7 installed? Is it the system Ruby 1.8.7 on a Mac? If so, DON'T try to install a gem to it - that way leads to trouble. Use RVM and install a copy in a sandbox, of either 1.8.7, or preferably 1.9.2. RVM makes this so easy to do. It's easy normally anyway, but RVM is even easier.

Comment: gem can install a locally stored gem bundle for you if you tell it what file to use, but, again, I do not recommend doing that to the System Ruby unless you really know what you are doing because that one is for the System's use.